# Setting up typeorm with nestjs not working migrations

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Here is the config:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
        entities: [
          __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
        ],
        // synchronize: true,
      })
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

The connections with the database itself is working, but when I'm trying to set up the migrations it throws the errors. What I've tried is to add the migration options in the above config and to create additional ormconfig.js with the configurations. Here is what I have in package.json file:

```
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

The problem is when I try to create migration it is not being created in migrations folder as I want and is not using the config above, how to solve it?

Comment: What's the errors throws ?

Comment: do you know that when using typeorm's CLI you didn't have the access to that `DatabaseModule`, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using typeorm or 3.0 or newer versions you should do it straight on the cli:

```
typeorm migration:create src/migration_path
```

For older versions, you can add the following command to the `ormconfig` file:

```
  "cli": {
    "migrationDir": "./src/migration_path"
  }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. However, just one more thing, if anyone need custom name for migration file then: ```typeorm migration:create  src/migrations/CoffeeRefactor```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set the migrations path in the module config

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    // other properties
    entities: [
      __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}', // from the question
    ],
    migrations:[/*I assume you already know migration file paths*/]
})
```

then, To generate a migration file

```
npx typeorm migration:create -n FileName -d src/migrations
```

At this point, you need to call `runMigrations()`. add the below code in your `main.ts`

```
const conn = await getConnection('default'); // connection name is "default"
await conn.runMigrations();
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM CLI reads the configuration in a file `ormconfig.json` or `ormconfig.js` at the root of the project.

You need to extract this config in suck a file and then import this file in your DatabaseModule to have both things working.